# Azure Service Bus - Messages body not getting printed in console. Code not getting in the for loop and taking a lot of time

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azureservicebus

```
with servicebus_client:
receiver = servicebus_client.get_subscription_receiver(topic_name=TOPIC_NAME, subscription_name=SUBSCRIPTION_NAME, max_wait_time=5)
with receiver:
    for msg in receiver:
        print("Received: " + str(msg))
        receiver.complete_message(msg)
```

This code is taken from the Azure service bus code snippet in Microsoft portal. The code works fine till the it sends the messages, but when it reaches this part of the code, it is not getting in the for loop. The print statement is not getting execute. But I can see the Incoming and outcoming messages on the particular metrics page of that topic. Can I get some help here as I am new to Azure Service Bus?

Answer (score 0):

---

Code for receive message from topic. its working as expected. you can try again with all library reference and follow all steps.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

namespace SubscriptionReceiver
{
    internal class Program
    {
        // connection string to your Service Bus namespace
        static string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://xxx/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxx";

        // name of the Service Bus topic
        static string topicName = "mytopic";

        // name of the subscription to the topic
        static string subscriptionName = "S1";

        // the client that owns the connection and can be used to create senders and receivers
        static ServiceBusClient client;

        // the processor that reads and processes messages from the subscription
        static ServiceBusProcessor processor;
        static async Task Main()
        {
            // The Service Bus client types are safe to cache and use as a singleton for the lifetime
            // of the application, which is best practice when messages are being published or read
            // regularly.
            //
            // Create the clients that we'll use for sending and processing messages.
            client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

            // create a processor that we can use to process the messages
            processor = client.CreateProcessor(topicName, subscriptionName, new ServiceBusProcessorOptions());

            try
            {
                // add handler to process messages
                processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;

                // add handler to process any errors
                processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;

                // start processing 
                await processor.StartProcessingAsync();

                Console.WriteLine("Wait for a minute and then press any key to end the processing");
                Console.ReadKey();

                // stop processing 
                Console.WriteLine("\nStopping the receiver...");
                await processor.StopProcessingAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Stopped receiving messages");
            }
            finally
            {
                // Calling DisposeAsync on client types is required to ensure that network
                // resources and other unmanaged objects are properly cleaned up.
                await processor.DisposeAsync();
                await client.DisposeAsync();
            }
        }

        // handle received messages
        static async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
        {
            string body = args.Message.Body.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine($"Received: {body} from subscription: {subscriptionName}");

            // complete the message. messages is deleted from the subscription. 
            await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
        }

        // handle any errors when receiving messages
        static Task ErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args.Exception.ToString());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :-** Receive Message from Topic Subscription

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am currently using Python for azure service bus. Can you help with the same using Python?